What happens to the current code if I delete a merged branch on BitBucket Cloud?
Someone accidentally created a branch called "bugfix" in our BitBucket Cloud repo some time ago, and this got merged onto develop and master.  This means we get a refs error if we try to push any branch which starts with bugfix, e.g. "bugfix/ABC-234_somefix"
We don't know how it was merged (e.g. if it was merge, or squash, or rebase or similar).
Can we assume it's safe to delete this old branch?

A branch is a "pointer" to a commit.
Commit(s) referenced by a branch still exist if the branch is removed. They are "harder" to find if they are no longer part of any branch though (you need to know either their hash for instance).
In case of the branch having been merged into another one, the commits are also "part of"/referenced by the other branch.
TL;DR: you can safely remove the branch if it's been merged. It won't delete anything in the commit history.
